# Is there different functionality in a wiki page and a page in a wiki page library?

Tags: sharepoint-server, wiki-pages

I am new to Sharepoint and have been tasked with developing our sharepoint wiki. I would like to create a template for my wiki pages created via the wiki page library. But all of the documentation I see is for an enterprise wiki. Will I be able to create a template? And if so, how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Wiki page is one of kinds page in the wiki page library. Wike page library includes wiki page、 web part page、 site page.